# Firebase hosting: how to generate a global 'map/array' that can be used on all pages instead of parsing the database on each page load

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

This question is not about a specific code but more about how to perform a certain task. I am lacking proper guidance and I am somewhat a beginner (hope this is allowed).

So there is a full built application (android + IOS + web) on Firebase, and I am dealing with the web part. I am accessing the database, getting data from it, generating arrays and maps from that data, and displaying what is needed from those arrays/maps on the website. All is working well.

However, here is how I am doing it: each page is calling a specific .js file (sometimes the same .js file), and most of the time I am recreating the same maps/arrays for each opened page (/on each page load). My question is, shouldn't there be a proper way of doing this? That is, create the maps/arrays on first access to the website (only once), and then just use them for each newly opened page instead of having to access the database each time a new page is opened (which is costly on the long run).

I believe this is similar to a 'session' idea in PHP. Should I be looking into node.js and how to create a session in node.js? (or is there a simpler way to do this?). Which titles or parts of node.js should I be looking into in order to do this task? (Any tutorial or suggestion is welcome).

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: So I was reading a bit further concerning sessions and it seems like they are more relevant to apps with registrations and logins (not what I am looking for). So I am back to block one and still lost about how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

After you get the data the first time, you could load it into the browser's `local storage`.

Then, as long as your web pages are on the same domain, the data can be re-accessed locally on the next page, instead of re-reading it from the database.

Here is a tutorial on browser `local storage`: https://javascript.info/localstorage

Hope that helps!